# Why does unordered_map increase in size when it has enough buckets due to "reserve"?

Tags: c++, c++14, hashtable, unordered-map

Consider this code. I reserve 6 spots for an unordered_map and insert 6 elements. Afterwards, there are 7 buckets. Why is this? The max_load_factor is 1 and there are enough buckets for the number of elements I insert.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  unordered_map<std::string,std::string> mymap = { 
            {"house","maison"},
            {"apple","pomme"},
            {"tree","arbre"},
            {"book","livre"},
            {"door","porte"},
            {"grapefruit","pamplemousse"}
  };

    unordered_map<std::string,std::string> mymap2; // THIS ONE!!!
    mymap2.reserve(6);
    for (auto i:mymap) {
        mymap2[i.first] = i.second;
    }


    std::cout << "max_load factor " << mymap2.max_load_factor() << " mymap has " << mymap2.bucket_count() << " buckets.\n";

      for (unsigned i=0; i<mymap2.bucket_count(); ++i) {
        cout << "bucket #" << i << " contains: ";
        for (auto it = mymap2.begin(i); it!=mymap2.end(i); ++it)
            cout << "[" << it->first << ":" << it->second << "] ";
          cout << endl;
      }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
max_load factor 1 mymap has 7 buckets.
bucket #0 contains: 
bucket #1 contains: [book:livre] 
bucket #2 contains: [tree:arbre] 
bucket #3 contains: [house:maison] [grapefruit:pamplemousse] 
bucket #4 contains: 
bucket #5 contains: [door:porte] 
bucket #6 contains: [apple:pomme]
```

Comment: If you print out the bucket count after `reserve(6)` it already has seven buckets, it seems (tried with g++ 10.2.0) so you don't even need to put anything in... If I ask for size 4 I get 5 buckets. Interesting. But then again, the documentation says "Sets the number of buckets in the container (bucket_count) to the most appropriate to contain at least n elements" so possibly having one extra is the most appropriate?

Comment: Seems the standard just says for `rehash(n)` (which this calls) that "ensures a.bucket_count() >= a.size() / a.max_load_factor() and a.bucket_count() >= n" so this seems an implementation specific choice possibly

Comment: It's trying to maintain a load factor less than a specific constant.

Answer (score 3):

The [cplusplus.com website](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/reserve/) gives this explanation:

```cpp
void reserve (size_type n);
```

> **Request a capacity change**
>
> Sets the number of buckets in the container (`bucket_count`) to the most appropriate to contain **at least** n elements.
>
> If n is greater than the current `bucket_count` multiplied by the `max_load_factor`, the container's `bucket_count` is increased and a rehash is forced.
>
> If n is lower than that, the function may have no effect.

At the time you declare your `unordered_map` variable,  it has a `bucket_count` of `1` and a `max_load_factor` of `1`.
Then you `reserve` `6` buckets which is greater than `max_load_factor` multiplied by `bucket_count`

According to this definition, the behavior is, in my humble opinion, correct.

I added at line `17` of your code the following line to show the `bucket_count` before the `reserve`and indeed, it is `1`

```cpp
 std::cout << "BEFORE RESERVE max_load factor " << mymap2.max_load_factor() << " mymap has " << mymap2.bucket_count() << " buckets.\n";
```

The display is as follows:

```bash
BEFORE RESERVE max_load factor 1 mymap has 1 buckets.
```

After the reserve:

```bash
AFTER RESERVE max_load factor 1 mymap has 7 buckets.
```

Thus the behavior is normal according to me.

Answer (score 3):

Hash table implementations tend to pick between two desirable qualities:

- maintaining a power-of-two `bucket_count()` (i.e. rounding any value passed to reserve up to the next power of two if necessary), so

  - a `size_t` value returned by the hash function can be mapped
    onto the range of buckets using a 1-CPU-cycle bitwise AND operation
    (e.g. 8 buckets -> hash value ANDed with 7);
  - this has the undesirable effect of chopping off the high-order bits from the hash value, so they don't help randomise the bucket placement
  - Visual C++ does this
- maintaining a prime `bucket_count()`

  - this has the extremely desirable side-effect of having high-order bits in the hash value affect the bucket selection, so lower-quality (i.e. faster) hash functions still often manage a more equal, less-collision/clustering-prone, bucket placement
  - implemented naively, this forces the compiler to do a mod ("%") operation by a runtime-variable `bucket_count()`, which may take e.g. 40-90 CPU cycles, depending on the CPU.  A faster alternative is use the index into the table of prime numbers used when sizing the hash table to switch into a mod operation by that hard-coded constant prime value, so the compiler can try to optimise the mod using bit shifts, subtractions or additions, or multiplications if that's necessary (you can see the kinds of optimisations possible in [this snippet on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/K45cYE))
  - GCC does this; I think clang does too.

So, summarily - when you ask for 6 buckets, GCC or clang will increase that to some prime - not necessarily the next one, but it appears that's happened in this case - to reduce the collision-proneness when you later insert elements.